# Фильтр отображения вопросов по избранным меткам

Tags: предложение, метки, избранные-метки

Если в настройках задать *избранные метки*, то вопросы по этим меткам отображаются в контейнере с персиковым задним фоном. При этом все остальные вопросы все равно также видны.

Немного нелогично, как мне кажется. Если я выбираю то, за чем я конкретно хочу наблюдать, то зачем мне все остальное? Это все равно что прийти в столовую, попросить гороховую кашу, но вместе с ней положат и гречневую и перловую и манную и рисовую, при этом гороховую отделив укропчиком.

Если зайти на http://stackexchange.com/ и нажать на *Filtered Questions* то может показаться что это то, о чем я говорю. Но, почему-то, выбрав теги на каком-либо из сайтов SO и попробовав посмотреть новые вопросы по выбранным тегам на *stackexchange->Filtered Questions* одновременно с новыми вопросами, выделенные персиковым, на том самом сайте - они вообще не совпадают.

Да, собственно, и лезть на exchange не очень удобно. Хочется видеть сразу отфильтрованные вопросы здесь и сейчас, без лишних телодвижений.

Может быть стоит сделать такую функцию, что при указании избранных меток - отображались только те вопросы, по которым метки выбраны? Или хотя бы поставить *checkbox*, который будет включать/отключать данное действие.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Эта задача достаточно просто решается использованием поиска: достаточно добавить одну из следующих ссылок к своим закладкам.

- [Новые вопросы с избранными метками](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=is%3aq%20intags%3amine)
- [Текущие вопросы с избранными метками](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=active&q=is%3aq%20intags%3amine)

Отмечу, что система навигации [находится в процессе полной переработки](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/308875). Бета-версия новой навигации пока доступна только на английском сайте Stack Overflow.

Comment: Да, но тогда смысл в настройках "избранные метки" в таком случае?)

Comment: Есть, поскольку параметр поиска `intags:mine` их использует.

Comment: Странно, но по `intags:mine` мне выдает слишком много лишнего например для `javascript` еще выдает `reactjs`, для `c#` выдает еще `.net`, для `sql` еще и `privileges`

Comment: В правой колонке показывается: "с метками: ...". Какие метки там находятся?

Comment: А, понял....с ними же еще метки идут.....Но смысла не меняет - это по сути собственный маленький костылек, нежели правильный функционал. имхо

Comment: Я согласен. Система навигации [находится на стадии полной переработки](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/308875). Бета-версия новой навигации пока доступна только на английском сайте Stack Overflow.

Comment: Аааа, Вооо, это прям шикарно. Предполагаю оттуда после тестов перекочует сюда. Значит надо просто подождать (хоть бы не год)) ), а пока воспользоваться поиском с intags.